# Executing bash scripts from Laravel

Tags: php, bash, laravel

I am writing an app in Laravel that will interact with the server by executing bash scripts.

These scripts will create ftp users and manage directories.

What are the best practices when approaching this?  I was thinking of writing a standard php function in laravel that would execute the bash script.  Is there anything better or a bridge that would allow me to interact with server management through a php backend?

I have found that laravel has SSH tasks built in, would this be suitable?

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh

Comment: you may use symfony [process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) which is used by laravel itself , and for sure . `ssh` would be pretty good to use;

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into Envoy which is made for this kind of tasks. Using Blade style syntax, you can easily setup tasks for deployment, Artisan commands, and more.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/envoy